# Why does m4 error "linux-gnu.m4 - No such file or directory" appear the first time after updating sendmail.mc?

Tags: email-server, sendmail

SendMail 8.14.x | CentOS 5.x

I've noticed that if I manually update /etc/mail/sendmail.mc (for example, enable TLS support), and then bounce sendmail, I get the following error:

```
Shutting down sm-client:                [   OK   ]
Shutting down sendmail:                 [   OK   ]
Starting sendmail: sendmail.mc:18: m4: cannot open `/usr/share/sendmail-cf/ostype/linux-gnu.mf': No such file or directory
                                        [   OK   ]
Starting sm-client:                     [   OK   ]
```

This only happens **one** time after I update a sendmail.mc file.  If I bounce sendmail again (without making any other change), I don't see the error any more.

Any idea why this happens?  It doesn't cause any errors - I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### sendmail.mc errors after upgrade

```
sendmail.mc:18: m4: cannot open `/usr/share/sendmail-cf/ostype/linux-gnu.m4': No such file or directory
```

Your `sendmail.mc` file is buggy. It contains `OSTYPE(linux-gnu)` directive without support for linux-gnu parameter for `OSTYPE`.  You get the above error message when sendmail package regenerates/recompiles `sendmail.mc` into `sendmail.cf` after upgrade.

**Suggested fixes** :
comment out OSTYPE line (`dnl ...`)
[Your sendmail works without it anyway as I understand]
**OR**
change OSTYPE parameter to value used in default sendmail.mc provided by sendmail packages in your distribution (centos?).  *It MAY cause unwanted/unexpected effects*.